# How to default value of java.util.Date type parameter in ireport?

Tags: java, date, jasper-reports, default

In iReport I want to set the default value of a java.util.Date type parameter to '8 September 2009'.

I tried setting this value in double quotes, with `new java.util.Date(2009,9,8)`, with `new java.util.Date(1252348200)` and with `new java.util.Date("08-09-2009")`, but none of these work.

How can one set the default value for a date parameter?

Comment: If this is static?, So why using Text Field, you can write it in Static text

Comment: This is not `String` type parameter. This is `java.util.Date` type parameter.

Comment: It's been over 3 years.  Did you ever get an answer to this?  I can't seem to find anything to work in the answers here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create new parameter set its type as java.util.Date and add in your text field's expression as

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy").format($P{dateParameter})
```

when you click preview a popup for input will appears.

**MORE**

*To add new parameter:*

click on Window -> Report Inspector (new palette will open on left pan) right click on parameter -> Add Parameter -> than set parameter class to 'java.util.Date' from its properties

*Set as Expression:*

Open expression editor of your field (right click -> Edit Expression) and paste

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy").format($P{dateParameter})
```

Comment: @varun its `dd MMMM, yyyy` for `08 September, 2009`

Comment: Ok. I used this code `new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy").format("08 September, 2009")` in default value expression but It did not work.

Comment: First thing in my comment. I was asking you If you Want Fixed date in your report, like this why you want parameter? Just use it as a static text what is the problem in it? As this is text field it required a db column which is in date.

Comment: I do not want fixed date in report, but only want to a default value in parameter when user sees a prompt for input.

Comment: Edited, than you need to add new parameter for it

Comment: What value should I set in new parameter?

Comment: At least give it a try, Current date or you want to like 8 Sep 09

Comment: That is the question which I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use calendar

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2009, 8, 8);
Date d = c.getTime();
```

Comment: c.set(2009, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 8); is more clear as months are 0 based

Comment: @Nitin Should I write your whole code in parameter?

Comment: This is a wrong solution. The question was about the JasperReports's expressions

Answer (score 0):

According to [Nitin Dandriyal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30366750/4580058):

You can use this code in the Default Value Expression using **GroovyShell** as follow:

```
new groovy.lang.GroovyShell().evaluate("Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.set(2009, 8, 8); return cal.getTime(); ")
```

**Update:**
[image]

Comment: `;` is not permitted in default value expression

Comment: I know, semikolon is used only in the scriptText, that returns a date result.

Comment: Got that. But this is still not working. I have checked **Use as a prompt**.

Comment: iReport is not showing any error but It is showing current date as default value when prompted to user.

Comment: Use Button "Use Default!", then you becomes Defult value in the report

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78395/discussion-between-vlad-and-varun).

Answer (score 0):

Pass a field/paramter, DATE_OBJ(java.util.Date) and a parameter, dateFormat(java.text.DateFormat) to the report. You can use a Calendar to set the required date on the DATE_OBJ
 Then the below expression should print your date.

Answer (score 0):

**I can't find any way to directly do this, but here's a workaround:**

1) First make the parameter's type `String` rather than `Date`.

2) Then enter a `Default value expression` for the date literal like this:  `"2018-01-23"`

3) Finally, use something like the following, which might need to get adjusted for the type of SQL you're using:

- For MariaDB (or MySQL) SQL use:  `STR_TO_DATE($P{From},"%Y-%m-%d")`, where you need to first replace 'From' with the name of your actual parameter.

This allows you to easily edit the default value as a string, and then use it as a date type in your SQL.

---

**SQL usage example:**

```
`WHERE `journal`.`Date` >=  STR_TO_DATE($P{From},"%Y-%m-%d")`
```

Answer (score -1):

The Date constructor with three parameters : year, month and day is **deprecated**. You should use instead the GregorianCalendar class. Howerver, if you really need a Date object, use the **getTime()**; method that returns a Date object from a GregorianCalendar instance.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2009, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 8);
Date myDate = gc.getTime();
```

Comment: `;` is not permitted in default value expression

Comment: I do not understant what you mean. Is there a problem with the code I gave to you ?

Comment: iReport says **Invalid character ;** when I write `;` in default value expression.

Comment: What is iReport o_O ?

Comment: I want to set default value for parameter in iReport.

Comment: This is a wrong solution. The question was about the JasperReports's expressions